# Null return when searching for ID in dynamic route

Tags: javascript, next.js

To test, I'm making an array of users with id and name with a button that calls the onclick function and adds the element's id to the page's url, with the aim of building a dynamic route.
When getting the id data, using useSearchParams, the return is null.

My code that redirects the user

```
'use client'

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const Users = () => {
  const { push } = useRouter()
  const users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'User 1', age: 15},
    { id: 2, name: 'User 2', age: 24}
  ]
  const handleEditUser = (id: number) => {
    push(`/pages/users/${id}`)
  } 
  return (
    <>
    <h1>Users</h1>

    {users.map((user) => {
      return (
      <div key={user.id}  onClick={() => handleEditUser(user.id)}  className="text-gray-200">
        <p>Id: {user.id}</p>
        <p>name: {user.name}</p>
        <p>age: {user.age}</p>
        <br />
      </div>
      )
    })}
    </>
  )
}
```

The code to show the id using useSearchParams is this:

```
'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

const UserDetail = () => {
  const id = useSearchParams()
  const userId = id.get('id')

  return (
    <div className="text-gray-200">
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <p>User ID from Router: {userId}</p>
    </div>
  );
};`

export default UserDetail;
```

The page structure is as follows:
app/pages/users/[id]/page.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to read the dynamic param (id) in this scenario.

**Option1:**

We can use [useParams](https://arc.net/l/quote/mtpbhjmi) function to retrieve an object that contains the dynamic parameters.

```
'use client'

import { useParams } from 'next/navigation';

const UserDetail = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const userId = params.id;

  return (
    <div className="text-gray-200">
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <p>User ID from Router: {userId}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Option 2:**
We can [access the dynamic segment directly](https://arc.net/l/quote/wpukwoml) from the component's params prop

```
const UserDetail = ({ params }) => {
  const userId = params.id;

  return (
    <div className="text-gray-200">
      <h1>User Details</h1>
      <p>User ID from Router: {userId}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The second approach is shorter since we don't need to import nor add 'use client'.

**The reason why your code was not working**

useSearchParams is used to return the query parameters in a URL e.g in the example URL

`https://www.example.com:8080/path/to/resource?param1=value1&param2=value2#section2`

The query parameter is "?param1=value1&param2=value2"

What you intend to retrieve are called **dynamic segments** and are parts of the url path that can have a dynamic value e.g. the [id].

Both the solutions above clarify how dynamic segments can be retrieved in next.js.

Comment: This has already been answered im not sure why you wouldn't just upvote my answer?

Comment: I upvoted it. I think you didn't cover everything and therefore provided a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

useSearchParams will only get things from the url params. For example if you have `/dashboard?search=username` the only thing that useSearchParams will return is the 'search' variable and not the 'dashboard'. I think you are looking for the `useParams` hook. This will allow you to get the id from the url that you passed in the previous component

```
'use client'
 
import { useParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const params = useParams<{ tag: string; item: string }>()
 
  // Route -> /shop/[tag]/[item]
  // URL -> /shop/shoes/nike-air-max-97
  // `params` -> { tag: 'shoes', item: 'nike-air-max-97' }
  console.log(params)
 
  return <></>
}
```